# ckeditor_rails doesn't work in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ckeditor

I'm using `ckeditor_rails` ([here](https://github.com/tsechingho/ckeditor-rails)) but when i uploaded my app to heroku, all my editors wasn't 'ck'ed (lol)
so I started my app (unicorn_rails -E production) and got the same result: even locally, the editors wasn't showing. if I start in development, they work pretty well...
here are my Gemfile (part of)

```
gem 'mongoid_slug'

# gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'will_paginate_mongoid'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate'

gem 'ckeditor_rails', :require => 'ckeditor-rails'
```

I tried `rake tmp:clear`and `rake assets:precompiled` and tried delete the `manifest.yml` too. none of these commands worked.
am I missing something?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you include the ckeditor-jquery
Make sure that your javascript and css files are included and precompiled

Comment: got it, it was the include. just placed right after `//= require jquery_ujs` make it